# ConTeXt: How to control vertical and horizontal line thickness in tables?

Tags: tables, context, context-mkiv, width

In LaTeX, I could do something like:

```
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth
  {X |[3pt] X}
  ...
\tabucline[3pt]{-}
  ...
\end{longtabu}
```

which would produce vertical and horizontal lines of `3pt` thickness. How to control line thickness in ConTeXt?

Comment: Which of the table mechanisms do you use? Usually the line width is controlled via the same  [``rulethickness``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE#Make_a_cell_bold) key as in ``\framed``.

Comment: @phg: Well, I'd like to use `tables`.

Comment: @phg: I've just noticed that `tables` are deprecated, and that `TABLE` is recommended. Then, I'd like to learn how to do it for `TABLE`.

Comment: @Haroogan: If you are starting from scratch, I would strongly suggest using `TABLE`. It is much nicer than the old `table` mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\starttext
\setupTABLE[row][each][rulethickness=.5pt,offset=\dimexpr1mm+2pt] 
\bTABLE
\bTR[rulethickness=5pt] \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2/3 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD[rulethickness=5pt,offset=1mm] 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 4 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 1 \eTD \bTD 2 \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: The question is relatively old. I've already mastered this topic. Anyway, I'm accepting your answer for the sake of completeness. Thanks.